# Cannot get the emulator running for my Android App using beeware (newbie)

Tags: python, android, android-emulator, beeware

I am using windows. As given in this link https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-5/android.html When I ran the app it is showing this error

```
In future, you can specify this device by running:

    briefcase run android -d @beePhone


Starting emulator beePhone...

Waiting for emulator to start...................
Android emulator was unable to start!

Try starting the emulator manually by running:

    C:\Users\Alok\.briefcase\tools\android_sdk\emulator\emulator.exe @beePhone -dns-server 8.8.8.8

Resolve any problems you discover, then try running your app again. You may
find this page helpful in diagnosing emulator problems.

    https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-vm
```

I have no clue how to resolve the issue. Even connecting my phone doesn't help as it is not showing up as an option. Can someone help? Please tell me a little in detail as I am new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone faces the same problem, it was solved. Just need to switch on USB debugging in developers option and then one can get the android device to show on the cmd.
Also, for using intel in android studio the desktop should have UEFI mode and not Legacy mode. If it is a legacy mode like mine you can use ARM but it is very slow.